# New Project has No Assemblies

Tags: c#, assemblies

I am new to c# and the first thing I am working on is a windows form application. However, I am receiving lots of weird reference errors and I have determined it is because there are no assemblies attached or linked(not sure of the proper term) to the project. I have downloaded someone else's project and i just keep reusing that file so I can have all the proper links. Is there a way to link all of these by default? When I check in the reference manager(on new projects), on the left, where 'Assemblies' should be there is only project, shared projects and browse. On the solution that I have downloaded there is also Assemblies. I know this is probably a noob question, but I cant really seem to fin the answer online or I may just not be asking the question correctly.
This is what my new project looks like:
[image]

This is what the downloaded one looks like:
[image]

Comment: what errors are you getting

Comment: Show your solution explorer and list at least some of the reference errors you are getting. Are you getting them a compile time?

Comment: Application.Run() is giving me this error: System.Runtime.InteropServices.StandardOleMarshalObject' from assembly 'System. It keeps telling me it cant find certain packages then i use nuget shell to install/reference them but ive reached a dead end.

Comment: but the only difference i can tell between the projects is the massive list of assemblies on the one that works. man the more I talk about this the more i realize i need to start coding more, i know its something dumb.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I am understanding your question properly, but I'll try to answer based on what I'm assuming.
You are looking for the referenced assemblies/libraries for your project, right?
Your references should appears in the solution explorer, under "References". Just like you can see here:

[image]

*I'm sorry for the redacted picture, but I'm working in a client's project, not mine

If some of the references are missing, then you will see a yellow-ish triangle (like a warning symbol) below the reference's name
If you do a right click on the reference's name, then you can go to properties, where you can find where your project is trying to find that assembly and the version of the library/assembly it is expecting to find. 
Example:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check your reference "System.Windows.Forms"

[image: reference]

If you don't find it, add it to the reference manager.

[image: reference manager]